# How can I play FLV video file in JWPLAYER in web-app on mobile devices?

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have tried and reseached everything about how to play flv video in mobile devices with **jwplayer video player**. I can run FLV in web-app on desktop but the same is not playing at mobile devices.

Can anyone have solution for this? Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to play an FLV file on mobile devices, because Adobe Flash is required to play FLV. This is true of JW Player and any other player.

You might have more luck if you can convert the video to MP4 or HLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here to see all the supported media formats for JW Player: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference

Answer (score 0):

According to JWplayer support, FLV and RTMP is not working in JWplayer for any mobile devices.

Please have a look of my conversation with support on twitter.

```
https://twitter.com/jwpsupport/status/745975377651085313
```

[image]